# Sending Login Details Using URL

Tags: c, url, authentication, passwords

I am attempting to automate a process.  I have setup a webpage with very basic security:

[image]

I want to automate the ability to log in.  The same username/password combination is used each time, but there are hundreds of IP addresses in use, so it would be tedious to use a password safe programme.

I am wondering if I can use something in the form of `url.com/?username=user&password=pass` to push the password through the security, without having to manually enter the details each time?

Comment: in plaintext? Not a very good idea, just sayin'.

Comment: I 100% appreciate and agree with that - but the passwords are common and well known!  I access these pages quite a bit over the course of a day so you can imagine my frustration.

Comment: Does this work for you: `http://username:password@url.com/` ?

Comment: Ah-ha!  It does for Firefox and Chrome, but not IE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me `http://username:password@url.com`.

***Note:*** I am using this on a secure network to save time, I do not recommend this is used outside of a controlled environment.